# What are the differences between the 1st and 2nd printings of the "Fiend Folio"?

Tags: adnd-1e, books

RPGGeek lists two printings for the original [Fiend Folio](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/43624/fiend-folio). So as to identify different printings, what are the observable differences (if any) between the first and second printing?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it changed? Errata wasn't common in the 1E era; I wouldn't expect anything beyond minor typographic fixes, at most.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: often there were minor differences in cover elements (e.g. different logos) or other inconsequential differences between printings that allowed identifying printings. This is more a matter of identifying the exact printing of books, rather than impact on usage.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, the 1ed *Deities & Demigods* famously had whole mythos eliminated from later printings...Without asking, how is OP to know the Fiend Folio didn't have similar changes?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Acaeum](https://acaeum.com/ddindexes/setpages/lateradd.html), the 2nd printing has both the ISBN and TSR product number on spine & lower left corner of back cover, while 1st has only ISBN in both places. Instead of the TSR product number on the back, the 1st printing has copyright information: "1981 TSR Hobbies, Inc.  All Rights Reserved." and "The designation 'TM' is used to designate trademarks owned by TSR Hobbies, Inc." Internally, the printings should be identical.